# How to get desired result set?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following two tables
**customers**

```
| customer_id | firstname | lastname | email                |
|-------------|-----------|----------|----------------------|
| 1001        | John      | Doe      | johndoe@gmail.com    |
| 1002        | Lorem     | Ipsum    | loremipsum@gmail.com |
| 1003        | Alph      | Beta     | alphabeta@gmail.com  |
```

And **orders**

```
| order_id | customer_id | via | status     |
|----------|-------------|-----|------------|
| 100      | 1001        | WEB | pending    |
| 101      | 1001        |     | pending    |
| 102      | 1001        | POS | pending    |
| 103      | 1002        | WEB | processing |
| 104      | 1002        | APP | pending    |
| 105      | 1001        | APP | completed  |
| 106      | 1003        |     | pending    |
```

I want to get the following resultset:

1. All the customers who have ordered via `WEB` or (EMPTY) but not from `POS`
2. All the customers who have ordered only via `APP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use an inner join between `customers` and `orders` where the `via` has the wanted values and a `NOT EXISTS` to check, that no unwanted `via` exists.

   ```
   SELECT c1.*
          FROM customers c1
               INNER JOIN orders o1
                          ON o1.customer_id = c1.customer_id
          WHERE o1.via IN ('WEB', '')
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                       FROM orders o2
                                       WHERE o2.customer_id = c1.customer_id
                                             AND o2.via = 'POS');
   ```

   (If the empty `via` is actually a `NULL` not an empty string, change `o1.via IN ('WEB', '')` to `coalesce(o1.via, '') IN ('WEB', '')` or to `o1.via = 'WEB' OR o1.via IS NULL`.)

   Alternatively you can do it just with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`.

   ```
   SELECT c1.*
          FROM customers c1
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM orders o1
                               WHERE o1.customer_id = c1.customer_id
                                     AND o1.via IN ('WEB', ''))
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM orders o2
                                 WHERE o2.customer_id = c1.customer_id
                                       AND o2.via = 'POS');
   ```

   (Again, if the empty `via` is actually a `NULL` not an empty string, change `o1.via IN ('WEB', '')` to `coalesce(o1.via, '') IN ('WEB', '')` or to `o1.via = 'WEB' OR o1.via IS NULL`.)
2. Again you can use a join and `NOT EXISTS`.

   ```
   SELECT c1.*
          FROM customers c1
               INNER JOIN orders o1
                          ON o1.customer_id = c1.customer_id
          WHERE o1.via = 'APP'
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                       FROM orders o2
                                       WHERE o2.customer_id = c1.customer_id
                                             AND o2.via <> 'APP');
   ```

   Or just use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`.

   ```
   SELECT c1.*
          FROM customers c1
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM orders o1
                               WHERE o1.customer_id = c1.customer_id
                                     AND o1.via = 'APP')
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM orders o2
                                 WHERE o2.customer_id = c1.customer_id
                                       AND o2.via <> 'APP');
   ```